# import external style sheet to Angular 5 project

Tags: css, angular5

How import external style sheet to the angular one component.

When i import like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bundle.css?v=2.1.0">
```

it works fine when testing. But it gives error when production building.

```
ERROR in : Couldn't resolve resource assets/css/bundle.css?v=2.1.0 from E:/Files/pro/src/app/test/test.component.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular CLI try add stylesheet path to angular-cli.json-> styles array , or upload stylesheet to server and link it to href .